# Javascript no longer updating value of input field

Tags: javascript

I wrote a Javascript function that would loop through rows of a table and update an input field in one of the cells. This code worked fine the last few months. I found out the first half of the problem was the  values stopped equating to true. This seems to work now, but the input value still does not update.

```
 function updateTable(accessionNumber, nanoDropValue) {
            $('#extractionTable tr').each(function () {
                let tableAccessionNumber = $(this).find('#accessionNumber').html();
                if (tableAccessionNumber === accessionNumber.toHtml) {
                    let inputField = $(this).find("input[id='nanodropReading']");
                    inputField.value = nanoDropValue;
                }
            })
```

Comment: It looks like you've mixed jQuery and native DOM property when setting the value. A tip: `.find` returns a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to strip out the jQuery and convert it all to Javascript and see how that works.